# Filtrado de resultados con AJAX y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

Buenas es la primera vez que estoy haciendo un filtrado de resultados, y de momento creo que voy bien, el problema que al aplicar en la consulta 3 filtros, hasta que no pongo los 3 no me arroja los resultados, tengo que hacer algo diferente???

Aquí lo que me traigo por POST:

```
$tipo =$_POST['tipoVivienda'];
$pob =$_POST['poblacion'];
$dist =$_POST['distrito'];
```

Aquí la construcción de la SQL para arrojar los resultados:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT vi.tipo_id, vi.vivienda_id, vi.localidad, vi.ciudad, vi.nombre, vi.foto, vi.estado_id, vi.etiqueta_id, vi.precio, vi.distrito,
   vi.metros, vi.habitaciones, vi.aseos, vi.banos, vi.descripcion, et.etiqueta_id, et.etiqueta AS nombreETQ, es.estado_id, es.estado, pb.poblacion_id, pb.poblacion, dis.distrito
   FROM vivienda AS vi
   LEFT JOIN  etiqueta AS et ON vi.etiqueta_id = et.etiqueta_id
   INNER JOIN estado AS es ON vi.estado_id = es.estado_id
   left JOIN poblacion AS pb ON vi.localidad = pb.poblacion_id
   left JOIN distrito AS dis ON vi.distrito = dis.distrito_id OR vi.tipo_id = $tipo OR vi.localidad = $pob OR vi.distrito = $dist");
   foreach ($results as $i => $res):
```

Answer (score 0):

No te muestra los resultados hasta que no pones los tres porque el select deja de funcionar bien,ya que sin dos de los datos queda algo así:`vi.tipo_id = OR vi.localidad = OR vi.distrito = $dist` (cosa que casca seguro). Donde recibes el post deberías de asegurarte de que todas las variables lleven datos, y en caso de que no asginarles algún valor como un string vacío `" "`. Esto lo puedes hacer fácil así:

`$tipo =$_POST['tipoVivienda'] ?? " ";
$pob =$_POST['poblacion'] ?? " ";
$dist =$_POST['distrito'] ?? " ";`

Las `??` son un "Operador Coalescente", el cuál indica  que en caso de que el `$_POST[]` no exista o contenga valores núlos la variable coja por defecto el valor a la derecha (el `" "`en este caso).

Por último te recomiendo que leas muy detenidamente este [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php). Que explica porque no debes de meter las variables php a 'pelo' en una consulta sql y los peligros que esto conlleva.

Un saludo, espero te sirva